# Ajax Toolkit AjaxFileUpload throw exception

Tags: asp.net, webforms, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I have an entry form which I want to add a file uploader I added a toolkit script manager to the master page
then i added an ajaxfileupload control `<http://www.asp.net/ajaxLibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/AjaxFileUpload/AjaxFileUpload.aspx>`

the aspx looks like this

```
<ajaxToolkit:AjaxFileUpload ID="AjaxFileUpload1" ThrobberID="myThrobber" ContextKeys="fred"
                AllowedFileTypes="jpg,jpeg" MaximumNumberOfFiles="2" runat="server" UploadedComplete="AjaxFileUpload1_UploadedComplete" />
```

the method AjaxFileUpload1_UploadedComplete is empty for now.

I got this exception and no event is firing except for the page_load

> Sys.ArgumentException: Sys.ArgumentException: Cannot deserialize. The
>   data does not correspond to valid JSON.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I realise this is an old question but i think this is caused by a 'bug' in the control. It appends query string parameters but assumes there are no existing parameters.

There are details and a fix here: https://ajaxcontroltoolkit.codeplex.com/workitem/27149 (involves changing the source and rebuilding the toolkit)