# Ajax HtmL Editor Image Upload JSON Error

Tags: c#, javascript, ajax, json

I have an AJAX HtmlEditorExtender on my page with the option to upload an image, however when I try to upload an image I get the following Error:

JavaScript runtime error: Sys.ArgumentException: Cannot de-serialize. The data does not correspond to valid JSON.
Parameter name: data

I have done some research on the error and saw some people saying this may be because i'm passing parameters through to the page using the query string. I was doing this so I removed the parameters and the error is still occurring, are there any other reasons this error could occur?

The exact same Html Editor Extender works on another one of my pages.

My HTML and C# is provided below:

```
<asp:HtmlEditorExtender ID="HtmlEditorExtender3" runat="server" TargetControlID="txtAdminAddNote" OnImageUploadComplete="MyHtmlEditorExtender_ImageUploadComplete">
            <Toolbar>
            <asp:InsertImage />
            </Toolbar>
            </asp:HtmlEditorExtender>

<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtAdminAddNote" TextMode="MultiLine" Width="96%" Height="200px"></asp:TextBox>  

protected void MyHtmlEditorExtender_ImageUploadComplete(object sender, AjaxFileUploadEventArgs e)
    {
        string filePath = "~/Images/" + Path.GetFileName(e.FileName);

        var ajaxFileUpload = (AjaxFileUpload)sender;
        ajaxFileUpload.SaveAs(MapPath(filePath));

        e.PostedUrl = Page.ResolveUrl(filePath);
    }
```

Comment: Do you get a call to MyHtmlEditorExtender_ImageUploadComplete before the exception occurs?

Comment: Also can you verify your editor isn't inside a visible=false parent? (see http://forums.asp.net/t/1948630.aspx?HTMLEditorExtender+Processing+an+image+upload)

Comment: Also also, is this the other question you were looking at? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10664264/ajax-toolkit-ajaxfileupload-throw-exception They mention a workaround in their answer's link

Comment: No, MyHtmlEditorExtender_ImageUploadComplete does not get called, however the page load does get called, it errors when it starts going through the javascript. It is in a parent element that WAS visible=false but at the time I try to upload an image using the extender it IS visible=true. And no that is not the question I saw however I have just tried the work-around and it causing more errors

Comment: Have you tried removing it from the parent that is conditionally invisible just to test if that's the issue?

Comment: wow didnt think about that and it has worked! been looking at this for a while now! If you put that as an answer ill mark it as correct, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue is [solved here](http://forums.asp.net/t/1948630.aspx?HTMLEditorExtender%20Processing%20an%20image%20upload) (I quote):

> From your description and error message, I think you have the
>   HtmlEditorExtender control in an initially invisible Panel control.
>
> For uploading image file, HtmlEditorExtender and AjaxFileUpload have
>   the same working principle.
>
> If so, please check below link.
>
> http://ajaxcontroltoolkit.codeplex.com/workitem/27307

Where the problem was that the `HtmlEditorExtender` control was **incidentally** (it's parent control was set to false) **invisible** at an integral part of the upload and therefore not processed correctly.

Move your  `HtmlEditorExtender` control outside any *possibly invisible* parent controls and test that this issue still occurs.